# Spring and serving files from outside of the web server

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want spring to serve certain files from the `/tmp...` directory, the specific directory isn't determined until shortly after the server starts so using `<mvc:resources location="/images/**" mapping="/absolute/path/to/image/dir"/>` won't seemingly work.

Comment: Stream them back from a controller; what specifically is the issue? What are those two parens supposed to be?

Comment: There is not specific issue, I just can't put the directory in the application-context.xml, because the directory that will be used is dynamically generated.

Comment: _How_ is the directory generated?

Comment: Of course there's a specific issue, otherwise you wouldn't be asking a question. If you know where the files are, or can find out via any means, I don't see what the problem is--there are any number of ways to give a web app information, but without knowing what you're actually doing, it's impossible to help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dave Newton noted - stream them from a controller. A very basic implementation:

```
@RequestMapping("/static/temp/{path}")
public void getResource(@PathVariable path, OutputStream os) {
     //TODO proper IO management
     InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/temp/" + path));
     IOUtils.copy(is, os);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/staticFile/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getPhotoRide2(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable int id) {
            try {
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("your file");
                OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                response.setContentType("your mime type");
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int count = 0;
                while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, count);
                }
               in.close();
               out.flush();
               out.close();
           } catch (Exception e) {}

}
```